# One line of table column toggling goodness. Almost

Tags: jquery

Here's my handy dandy line of code:

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function(){$(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child('+$(this).prevAll().length+')').andSelf().toggle();});
```

Now... in theory, I thought that what this should do was take any th with class "subhead" in the table id'd as options and go find any td of the same column and toggle it. Oh, as well as the original th.

Guess what. It wipes out and returns the whole contents of the table.

I'm missing something here. Is "this" where I'm doing preVall and length no longer the this I'm thinking of?

Update!
wirey got my closer with his comment.

I'm here now:

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function(){$(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child('+$(this).prevAll().length+')').toggle();}).toggle();
```

This works great EXCEPT that it is hiding the wrong td's. It seems to be one column over on the first one, correct on the next two and one column to the left on the last one. LOL

UPDATE 2.5 (due to bad url):

I made a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/8nTXB/1/

UPDATE 3
Got it thanks to wirey. Here's the final fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/8nTXB/2/

And the completed line of code.

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function () {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).prevAll().length+1) + ')').toggle();
}).toggle();
```

Comment: A javascript debugger would easily help you see what `this` really is at each step.

Comment: You said andSelf()... so it adds the whole table in the collection

Comment: handy dandy? goodness? id'd? the this i'm thinking of?

Comment: What? I can't be conversational in my code humping madness? Pa-lease.

Comment: @MatthewDavis try to add 1 to the prevAll.length because :nth-child is 1 indexed and not zero indexed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your mistake

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function(){
    $(this) // <-- you're at the th level
    .parents('table') // <-- now your at the table level
    .find('td:nth-child('+$(this).prevAll().length+')') // you traversed down
    .andSelf() // <-- this says add the previous element in the stack which is the table
    .toggle(); // here you are toggling the tds and the table
});
```

You try it like this - not tested

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function(){
    $(this) // <-- you're at the th level
    .parents('table') // <-- now your at the table level
    .find('td:nth-child('+$(this).prevAll().length+')') // you traversed down
    .end()  // <-- now back at the table level in the stack
    .andSelf() // <-- this says previous elements in the stack which is the TH
    .toggle(); // here you are toggling the th and tds
});
```

just FYI, if you are using jQuery 1.8+ then you should be using [.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) instead since .andSelf() has been deprecated

**EDIT**

[:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) is 1-indexed and not zero-inexed so you need to add 1 to prevAll().length

```
$('#options th.subhead').each(function () {
  $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).prevAll().length+1) + ')').toggle();
}).toggle();
```

Comment: Close but no tomato. I AM using 1.8+ so thanks for that. Had no idea. (Been cleaning .live() from a lot of code lately. Anyway, no, that wipes out the whole shpeal, just like mine did. However, your first comment about having andself got me to move it out of that bracket, and I got closer. See upcoming edit.

Comment: That got it! Thanks wirey.... maybe for my next question you can explain why I got two down votes on this question.

Comment: Hehe.. I'm not sure..  I didn't downvote.. People should really explain why they downvoted so the person knows what they did wrong..  Glad you got it working :)

Comment: haha.. I didn't even see that you made a fiddle.. I just remembered you could have just used `.add(this)` instead of `.andSelf()`

Comment: As far as downvotes go, I've decided it's because I'm too awesome. :)